# Qgis map is disfunctional

Tags: qgis

Of recent I have this problem with Qgis 2.14 that my map composer won't produce a map of my project but instead it goes all blank. I even used 2.12 and even after uninstall/install the problem still persists.
What could possibly the problem?
I run a windows 10 OS on an i3 hp

Comment: does the map appear in composer, but results in an empty image/pdf when you export? Or does it appear blank in the map composer window too?

Comment: The map project appears on the map composer canvas but when I launch the conversion to picture, pdf or svg, the canvas disappears and never returns until I delete it and run another map composer. I recently tried it on a friend's machine and somehow discovered that his machine developed the same problem when I tried to convert the project into a picture **ALONGSIDE the OSM layer as base map**. Well our machines are all down with this problem now and I am kind of confused on what next to do.

Comment: you mention using OSM as a base layer. Are using the OpenLayers plugin? If so, try QuickMapServices instead, it works a lot better than OpenLayers plugin with Map Composer.